# Opencart- Check if user is on category page

Tags: php, opencart

I've a requirement where the product search and Login/Register links must be displayed only if the user is on Category Pages. That block should not be displayed while on the Static Footer pages as Contact Us or other static footer links.

Weird as it may be the client has very specific requirements regarding this thing.

I've worked on my own with the help in community as much as I can get. But so far I've been able to enable or disable the block completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be:

edit the template file `catalog/view/template/your_theme/product/category.tpl` and add the search input and login/register links directly to that template (somewhere) while positioning with CSS properly to meet Your needs.

Then edit the controller file `catalog/controller/product/category.php` and copy here the pieces of code from `catalog/controller/common/header.php` for the login/register links.

Of course edit `catalog/view/template/your_theme/common/header.tpl` and remove the search input and login/register links from here.

This should be enough...

Another solution:

- copy `catalog/view/template/your_theme/common/header.tpl` to `catalog/view/template/your_theme/common/header_category.tpl`
- copy `catalog/controller/common/header.php` to `catalog/controller/common/header_category.php`
- edit `catalog/view/template/your_theme/common/header.tpl` and remove the search input and register/login links...
- edit `catalog/controller/product/category.php` and find the piece code like `$this->data['children'] = array(...);` -> here replace the `header` with `header_category`

Never done this but it might work...

Comment: Yes... This is better but going through CSS positions would screw some other elements. But solution none the less

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found this article that gave me exactly what I wanted...

http://craigmurray.me.uk/opencart-mods/how-to-highlight-the-current-category-in-the-header-in-opencart/

I made

```
if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {

<<DISPLAY SECTION>>

}
```

But not sure if this would work if the links are made to be SEO friendly.
For now this is working.